# Failed to start build on agent because of Snapshot dependency failure

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I've configured build chain on TC.
When some build fails, dependent build shows error "Failed to start ... build on agent ..." and "Snapshot dependency failure".

Dependent build is configured to start ONLY in case of previous build succeeded. Also dependent build is configured to have the same build id as it's dependency (correspond to revision number) and thus I'm able to see last successfull commit that had been passed "the testing chain". With this in mind I don't see any advantages in "Failed to start" error message to be shown, in contrary my project page on TC is less readable. How could I configure TC not to show it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution?